# Probability and set theory proof

Tags: probability-theory

Given a collection of (mutually) independent subsets $(A_i)_{i∈N_+}$ of Ω, prove that for any sub-collection of sets $({A_i}_{j})_{j∈1,...,k}$

$$\Bbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^kA_{ij}\right)=1-\prod_{j=1}^k\left(1-\Bbb{P}(A_{ij})\right)$$

I have got no idea on how to prove that.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\bigcup A_i = \left(\bigcap A_i^c\right)^c$$
where $A^c$ is the complement of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^kA_{ij}^c\right)=\prod_{j=1}^k(1-\mathbb{P}(A_{ij}))\quad (*)$$

We prove by induction, if $k=2$, then
$$\begin{aligned}\mathbb{P}(A_{i1}^c\cap A_{i2}^c)=&\mathbb{P}(\Omega\cap A_{i2}^c)-\mathbb{P}(A_{i1}\cap A_{i2}^c)\\
=&\mathbb{P}(A_{i2}^c)-[\mathbb{P}(A_{i1}\cap\Omega)-\mathbb{P}(A_{i1}\cap A_{i2})]\\
=&\mathbb{P}(A_{i2}^c)-[\mathbb{P}(A_{i1})-\mathbb{P}(A_{i1})\mathbb{P}(A_{i2})]\\
=&(1-\mathbb{P}(A_{i2}))-(1-\mathbb{P}(A_{i2}))\mathbb{P}(A_{i1})\\
=&(1-\mathbb{P}(A_{i2}))(1-\mathbb{P}(A_{i1}))
\end{aligned}$$

Then by inductive argument $(*)$ can be proved for arbitrary $k$. Thus the result follows.